# burn.ancestors in wix 3.9

Tags: wix, burn

I recently upgraded to the latest stable Wix 3.9 from 3.8.  Now when I run a bundle upgrade against a bundle that was built using 3.8, 3.9 passes a command line argument of "-burn.ancestors={some guid}".  In the log I see a message like this: "w002: Unknown burn internal command-line switch encountered: 'burn.ancestors={some guid}".  The upgrade appears to go through the normal processes after that, so my question is this:  What does this argument do, and is there any need for concern when seeing this message?

This message does not come up in the log if upgrading a bundle that was built with 3.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for concern when seeing `Unknown burn internal command-line switch encountered`.  As features are added to the Burn engine, command line parameters will be added.  Command line parameters like `burn.ancestors` are passed to all child bundles, since Burn doesn't know which version of Burn is in the child bundle.

This switch was added as a part of a [huge pull request from Microsoft](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/pull/15) that is supposed to address many issues described in [issue 4242](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4242/).  It appears to be used for infinite loop detection.

Comment: anyone know if there is a way to disable this parameter from being passed?  I have a 3rd party install I'm trying to bundle and it complains that it doesn't understand the parameter and then fails to install.